# How to draw diagonal gradient?

Tags: delphi, gradient

How do I draw a diagonal gradient with three colors ?

Here's an example:

[image: il mio gradiente]

Comment: IIRC GraphUtils unit has gradient fill routines.

Comment: don't close it yet. people are working on answers. :)

Comment: goddamnit. I click on "post your answer", and somebody closed in the meantime, without even bothering to read comments.

Comment: Closed by people who don't even understand Delphi, but they want their badge for closing 10000 questions. I never saw b__ and Nitin Gohel do anything useful under the Delphi tag. Annoying!

Comment: @Wouter: You should do as TLama! :) Anyhow, it will soon be open again!

Comment: Voted for reopening. This can be a tricky one if the angle is <> 45 degrees.

Comment: @LURD : I have the code that generates the image right here.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: Here you go.

Comment: Let me add one off-topic note, there is a nice application for "playing" with the [`GradientFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144957(v=vs.85).aspx) function downloadable through [`this article`](http://www.flounder.com/gradientfiller.htm), which is also pretty well written.

Comment: Flounder rocks! (This Q does not)

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 6):

OK, drop a TPaintbox on your form, and add this OnPaint handler:

```
procedure TForm53.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp  : TBitmap;
  x,y  : integer;
  r,g,b: byte;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.SetSize(256, 256);

    for y   := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do
      for x := 0 to bmp.Width - 1 do
      begin
        r := 0;
        g := round(256 * max(0, y - x) / PaintBox1.Height);
        b := round(256 * max(0, x - y) / PaintBox1.Width);
        bmp.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := RGB(r, g, b);
      end;

    PaintBox1.Canvas.StretchDraw(PaintBox1.ClientRect, bmp);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That should look like your example.

Explanation:
It generates a 256x256 off-screen bitmap to draw to. 
When it's done, it's painted to your paintbox control.

It loops through all pixels of the bitmap, and for each bitmap, it calculates the color, as Red, Green and Blue.

Comment: I see LU RD's point now. If it's not 45 degrees, you'll have to do it different.

Comment: @TLama, this was just a quick example. I personally use Graphics32 for this kind of stuff, and lately I'd let the GPU do the work via a shader. https://www.shadertoy.com/user/WouterVanNifterick/sort=newest 
I've written a library that implements almost all GLSL constructs in Delphi, but it clearly shows that the CPU can never match the speed of GPU's for this type of work.

Comment: I see. I was just kidding :-)

Comment: Just shared the mentioned code here: https://code.google.com/p/delphi-shader/

Comment: Just adding SetWorldTransform for the PaintBox1.Canvas would enable you to use the code with any rotation.

Comment: This seems very interesting, but is converted into xe2:
http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/files/pegtopcommon.zip and
http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/files/PegtopCommonDemo.exe